# When QR outperform SVD to estimate column space of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: svd

I have a symmetric matrix, $\hat{A}, $which is an estimator of another true symmetric matrix, $A$.  I would like to estimate the column space of $A$.  I know I can do QR-Algorithm or use spectral decomposition to find non-zero eigenvectors of $\hat{A}$ and use these vectors to generate the column space.

I was wondering when QR give a better estimator than the spectral decomposition method.

Comment: What is meant by estimating the column space of $A$? There are many different techniques that are used to measure this. But if you're trying to minimize $\| \hat{A} - A \|_2$ then the SVD is optimal.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually want to minimize the norm of $P_{\hat{A}} - P_{A}$, where $P_{A}$ is the orthogonal projector to column space of $A$.  I know that SVD is optimal in general, but I believe there are cases it would be outperformed QR.  I am trying to find examples when SVD is worse than QR.